# Identifier ecmascript 2017 specification

Tags: javascript, unicode, compiler-construction, grammar, lexer

Hello from [ecmascript specifications](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-UnicodeIDStart)

```
UnicodeIDStart::
   any Unicode code point with the Unicode property "ID_Start"
UnicodeIDContinue::
   any Unicode code point with the Unicode property "ID_Continue"
```

What are the the Unicode property "ID_Start" and "ID_Continue"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to [Unicode character properties](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Properties). As [the ES spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-names-and-keywords) says

> *IdentifierName* and *ReservedWord* are tokens that are interpreted according to the Default Identifier Syntax given in Unicode Standard Annex #31, Identifier and Pattern Syntax […]. The Unicode identifier grammar is based on character properties specified by the Unicode Standard.

[That standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr31/#Default_Identifier_Syntax) is also referenced in the [bibliography](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-bibliography) of the spec.